# INSERT Multiple Database Values To Specific Rows

Tags: php, mysql

How can I INSERT the values of this function to only WHERE the value of the `username` column (located in the `login` table, contains the exact same value as the value of the column `nickname` (located in a table called `active_users`).

```
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO login (device_token) VALUES (?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($token));
```

Additional info: when a user logs in, I set up the API to add the user's name to both `username` (in the login table) and `nickname` in the active_users table. Since these values will always be the same for their respective tables, I was hoping we could add some conditional logic to achieve this type of specificity. My goal is to take the device_token parameter and pass it to a different spot in the database.

**Edit**: Schema

[image: active_users table]

[image: login table]

[image]

[image]

**Update** AFNetworking command for login

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command", _nicknameTextField.text = fldUsername.text, @"username", hashedPassword, @"password", nil ];
```

**Update**: active_users INSERT statment

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO active_users (user_Id, device_token, nickname, secret_code, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($userId, $token, $name, $code, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

Comment: I think you should show us the schema of your tables.

Comment: I am using multiple tables in my database. One handles the users login info and the other keeps track of that user as well as gives them a device_token. I want to update the device token column when the user logs in

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, you need to use a join (most likely a LEFT join) however, until I see your schema I cannot help you.  A schema being your table definitions and the fields.

Comment: you should ad a foreign key to your second table and update the token while the user login by the foreign key

Comment: Thank you @ash; I've realized the best way to do it thanks to all of your input

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly. What you really want is an update and not an insert.
You want to add the value of device_token to the row with nickname, correct?

You would do that with an update:

```
UPDATE login
SET device_token = @token
WHERE username = @nickname
```

If you're trying to update the record with an existing record from active_users table than:

```
UPDATE login AS L
JOIN active_users AU ON L.username = AU.nickname
SET L.device_token = AU.device_token
```

Though, looking at your tables. I'm wondering if you're repeating too much of the data. It seems like you can link login and active_users by user_id. Well, this would get off topic, so I'll just suggest double checking db design concepts and your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to join that statement with the active_users table so that it knows that thats where the nickname statement is?

Comment: @Program1 I edited my question. Was that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that would work though for some reason it still skips a line so that even though the login device_token field gets updated, it still needs to be specifically associated with the current user. Picture update above

Comment: The thing is the user_id in the active_users table is dynamic and is always changing. I was hoping the fact that the values for nickname and username are the same would be sufficient.  I updated my post: the last picture shows what happens when I sign up with a username of "Santiago" after using the JOIN statement. Notice how it just skips a line altogether

Comment: That's very odd. It should not create a new record if you are doing an update.

Comment: I noticed that image, and I also see that the token went in before the nickname was in there. The assigned sequential PK is 86 for the token and 87 for the username. Do you still have an insert statement for the token somewhere else?

Comment: Yes its still being updated in the active_users table. Ill post the code above

Comment: Updated with the active_users INSERT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101688/discussion-between-santiago-and-program1).

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO it should be

```
UPDATE login
SET device_token = :token
WHERE username = :nickname
```

where the params array that will be bound looks like

```
$params = array("token" => $token, "nickname" => $nickname);
```

Full example:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE login SET device_token=:token WHERE nickname=:nickname');
$stmt->execute(array("token" => $token, "nickname" => $nickname));
```

Or you use the method of binding with ?

```
UPDATE login
SET device_token = ?
WHERE username = ?
```

where the parameter array is

```
$params = array($token, $nickname);
```

Full example:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE login SET device_token=? WHERE nickname=?');
$stmt->execute(array($token, $nickname));
```

Comment: After changing your code to replace nickname with username, I signed up with the username `electric` and the device_token gets added to a new line still. I want it to be added to the same row with the electric username.  Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry - of course it should be UPDATE active_users ... if you want to update the active_users table
Prerequisite is, that the user with the nickname already exists in the active_users table

Or should the token be set in the login table??

Comment: The token should be set in login table. Thats where It will be used.

Comment: Additional info: the active_users table has a nickname field (associated with the device_token that we want to pass to the login table's device_token field)

Comment: How do you set the information in the login table now? So how is the username set there?

Comment: The app uses $_Post to update those values via AFNetworking.

Comment: Ok seems like the login isn't set, when you do the update query. Do you have the possibility to execute above mentioned query after the post via AFNetworking?
Or may it possible to provide the codesnippet, where the login table is written?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely an option to post via AFNetworking. I thought it would be easier via pure php. I will post the AFNetworking call that does the login command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestions @Andreas you have definitely reassured my assumptions about the API; you're totally right, it would be easier to just make the call via AFNetworking to pass the device_token value to where the login tables is expecting it at the time of sign up!

Comment: Ok - so the login is done via AFNetworking or does it only pass the data to php and the php writes the data into the login table?
If so, you can enrich the $_POST data with the token selected from the active_users table and then insert into the login table.

Comment: AFNetworking is used to communicate with the php API. My plan is to just add a device_token parameters to the above AFNetworking method so it updates the device_token field in the database when the user signs up or logs in

Comment: Yeah i think then it would be best/easiest to do like you said in your comment before.